# Convert an exsiting jsp project to use Framework

Tags: java, spring, jsp, frameworks, web

A few months ago, I started to work on an existing web project written in Jsp. No framework had been used before. The project is pretty big, using Tomcat + MySQL database.

I thought of converting the project to use Framework, and more specific, I thought of using Spring.

The main question: how hard can the conversion be?

1. Does spring support managing an exist database (without cdo any change to anyfield/name/etc in the db)?

   For example, managing users and permissions done by the project code, and I would like to change it to use existing managing module that Spring has.
2. will I need to change all my queries to a different format ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: SQL is SQL; if you use Spring JDBC you'll just move them and update how the SQL gets any of its params. There's no way to determine how hard the conversion will be, it depends on how the existing code is structured, how good you are with Spring, etc.

Comment: As for JSP. You can still use JSP as views with spring MVC for example.

Answer (score 0):

after a year+ i can answer my self. SQL and JPA and JPQL has a lot of common, but also has alot of difference. 
 for A. you can use existing db with spring. 
 B. depends, if you want to use spring jpa power so yes. if you want to use native sql so no.